# Error when building on Android 12: APK file won't install due to android:exported property

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

I'm trying to build my application for Android 12, but I'm encountering an issue related to the android:exported property. I've recently read that in Android 12 and later versions, it's necessary to explicitly set this property for all components in the manifest. However, even after configuring android:exported for all activities, services, and broadcast receivers with intent filters in my manifest file, I still can't install the application.

I've reviewed the manifest file multiple times and ensured that all android:exported properties are set correctly, but the problem persists. The error message I receive when trying to install the application says, "Error: APK file cannot be installed on this device."

I've consulted the official documentation for Android 12 and release notes, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue. Has anyone else faced a similar situation or does anyone have any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Any help or insights into resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
  package="com.myapp.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
      <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
      <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver" android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
      <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" android:exported="false"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="myCall">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="myapp"
                    android:host="call"
                     />
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="demo" />
          <data android:host="first" />
          <data android:host="second" />
          <data android:host="third" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="miapp" android:host="miapp" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="jw"
                    android:host="home" />
            <data android:scheme="jw"
                    android:host="Messages" />
            <data android:scheme="jw"
                    android:host="SearchResult" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"  android:exported="true"/>
      <service android:name="com.voximplant.foregroundservice.VIForegroundService" android:exported="true"> </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You need `MainActivity` to be exported. Otherwise, launcher apps cannot start it.

Comment: Thank you, I made the correction but the error continues, I even tried to upload the abb to playstore but it returns this error ''You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that has an activity, activity alias, service, or broadcast receiver with intent filtering, but without setting the android:exported property. This file cannot be installed on Android 12 or later. See developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported"

Comment: Is it your own AndroidManifest or the merged one? If you use some external libraries, dependencies they may include components that don't conform to the `exported` requirments. Use "Merge Manifest" tab for the manifest file in the Android Studio to detect the problem.